# Arango restarts on a random basis when same traversal query is performed

Tags: arangodb

I am running a series of simultaneous requests from a node server to an Ubuntu AWS Instance with Arango installed. Arangod is version 3.1.7

Everything worked fine for a few weeks, but now :

On a random basis, I get an {Error: socket hang up} from node while performing on of my queries, always the same one, and arango seems to restart as I get {Error: connect ECONNREFUSED} on all other queries for a little while.
It happens 1 out of 6 times, although my data did not change between queries.

Web Interface logs are very few and don’t seem to explain what went wrong. Arangod seems to create a logfile, but it is very hard to interpret.
All server metrics are fine.

Do you have ideas on how can I move forward on this issue ? Is my data corrupted ? How can I find out ?

Here is the content of my logfiles :

```
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO ArangoDB 3.1.7 [linux] 64bit, using VPack 0.1.30, ICU 54.1, V8 5.0.71.39, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO using SSL options: SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE, SSL_OP_TLS_ROLLBACK_BUG
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO Authentication is turned on
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO Authentication system only
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO Authentication for unix sockets is turned on
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 131072, soft limit is 131072
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO running WAL recovery (1 logfiles)
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO replaying WAL logfile '/vol/data/standalone/journals/logfile-44002553.db' (1 of 1)
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO WAL recovery finished successfully
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO JavaScript using startup '/usr/share/arangodb3/js', application '/var/lib/arangodb3-apps'
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO In database '_system': Database is up-to-date (30107/standalone/existing)
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO In database 'X-DB': Database is up-to-date (30107/standalone/existing)
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [11449] INFO using endpoint 'http+tcp://0.0.0.0:8529' for non-encrypted requests
2017-02-22T16:24:58Z [11449] INFO Please note that a new bugfix version '3.1.11' is available
2017-02-22T16:24:58Z [11449] INFO ArangoDB (version 3.1.7 [linux]) is ready for business. Have fun!
```

And :

```
2017-02-22T16:24:57Z [1311] ERROR {startup} child 11302 died a horrible death, signal 11
2017-02-22T16:27:57Z [1311] ERROR {startup} child 11449 died a horrible death, signal 11
```

I believe the query causing the trouble is :

```
RETURN (
FOR i, j, k IN 0..3 INBOUND "Hint/26427214" GRAPH "X-graph"
FILTER k.vertices[1]._id LIKE "Drop/%"
AND k.vertices[2]._id LIKE "Hint/%"
AND k.vertices[3]._id LIKE "Drop/%"
FILTER k.vertices[1].hostname != k.vertices[3].hostname
FILTER k.vertices[2].type == "article"
SORT k.vertices[2].createdAt DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
RETURN UNION (
FOR v, e, p IN 0..2 INBOUND k.vertices[2]._id GRAPH "X-graph"
FILTER p.vertices[1]._id LIKE "Source/%"
AND p.vertices[2]._id LIKE "Twittos/%"
RETURN { key: p.vertices[0]._key, retweets: p.vertices[0].retweets, title: p.vertices[0].title, type: p.vertices[0].type, content: p.vertices[0].content, image: p.vertices[0].image, source: { key: p.vertices[1]._key, name: p.vertices[1].name, screenname: p.vertices[2].screenname, image: p.vertices[2].image }},
FOR v, e, p IN 0..1 INBOUND k.vertices[2]._id GRAPH "X-graph"
FILTER p.vertices[1]._id LIKE "Source/%"
RETURN { key: p.vertices[0]._key, retweets: p.vertices[0].retweets, title: p.vertices[0].title, type: p.vertices[0].type, content: p.vertices[0].content, image: p.vertices[0].image, source: { key: p.vertices[1]._key, name: p.vertices[1].name }},
FOR v, e, p IN 0 INBOUND k.vertices[2]._id GRAPH "X-graph" RETURN { key: p.vertices[0]._key, retweets: p.vertices[0].retweets, title: p.vertices[0].title, type: p.vertices[0].type, image: p.vertices[0].image, content: p.vertices[0].content })[0] )[*]
```

Comment: If ArangoDB restarts automatically it looks like it's crashing. There is a supervisor process for ArangoDB that will restart arangod automatically. That supervisor process will write a log message when it detects that the database has crashed. There should be two logfiles in `/var/log/arangodb3` (path may be different depending on platform), and in one of them there should be indications about whether there were crashes or not.

Comment: If it is crashing, it would be good to know which version of ArangoDB is in use and if there is a specific query that causes ArangoDB to fail. If you can find out the specific query and post it here that will probably help reproduce and fix the problem. If you cannot find out which query it is, it may help to enable coredumps on the server so the OS will write an image of the arangod process when it crashes. Such corefile should also help us find the error. Thanks!

Comment: Another fix attempt is to upgrade the installed ArangoDB package to the latest version and check if the error has been fixed there. It's hard to tell from here whether that will help in your case because the question does not contain any information about the ArangoDB version in use.

Comment: @stj I added my arango version (3.1.7), my logfiles and the query that causes the trouble.
How can I enable coredumps and get the corefile ?

Comment: Having this issue with version 3.6.1.1. After calling traversal query, arangoDB crashes with restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I tried to simply upgrade to arangod 3.1.11. The issue seems to be gone.

Comment: Glad that it works now. There have been some fixes for traversal filter conditions in 3.1.10. The issue you have had was probably related to these issues.